# add value to an existing record

Tags: sql, sql-server

trying to add a value to an existing record by using the update statement, the field is text and the add operator is incompatible with a text field. See Example below.

```
update Notes
set note = note + 'test'
where note = 'start'
```

Notes Table

```
  |Note                 |
  -----------------------
  |First note. star test|
  |Second note. end     |
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: Use `=` for equals comparison. Perhaps you want `LIKE` instead, to find the first row.

Comment: `text` was deprecated when SQL Server 2005 was released. Why are you still using it in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a select with an update statement

```
UPDATE
    Notes
SET
    note = CONCAT(N.note, 'test')
FROM
    Notes AS N
WHERE
    N.note = 'start'
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST/CONVERT to `varchar(max)` while doing the concatenation.